# PHP replace class function with a string

Tags: php, string, function, class, methods

Many questions before about this topic. Still I can't solve it.

**Does work**

```
echo $page->omdome1_text()->value();
```

**Does not work**

```
$number = 1;
echo $page->omdome{'number'}_text()->value();
```

What is wrong with the last one?

Comment: `echo $page->{'omdome' . $number . '_text'}()->value();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the way to concatenate strings in php, even apart from the fact that you are not using your variable but a constant string.

You would need something like:

```
$number = 1;
echo $page->{"omdome{$number}_text"}()->value();
```

or:

```
$number = 1;
$method = "omdome{$number}_text";
echo $page->{$method}()->value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because rather than parsing the variable `$number`, you are parsing the string "number".

Do it like this:

```
$number = 1;
echo $page->omdome{$number}_text()->value();
```

Comment: '$number' will still take it as a string. Removing single quotes will do the job :).

Comment: @Samir haha yeah, just noticed that